# Update Cloud Build ref to show correct branch it ran on

Tags: google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I'm using a webhook trigger and part of the configuration requires setting a default branch. This webhook invokes on pull requests so when the trigger runs it check-out that branch.

Everything works great except that in the Cloud Build history it obviously doesn't show the branch it ran on but the default branch set in the configuration, ie. 'master'

Is it possible to update the `ref` during build to be the actual branch it executed on so there is a bit more clarity when reviewing build history?

Referring to this documentation here, have I found the correct variable and would reassigning it work?

```
steps:
  - id: 'Setup Credentials'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      # checkout 'feature/my-branch' branch
      # do work on branch
      $_REF_EVENT_NAME='feature/my-branch' # overwrite the configured default branch
```

[image: screenshot]

If its possible then I'd want to update the commit reference as well as that's from the masters last commit not the branch.

Comment: AKAIK, you can't. This ref column is important when you use other type of trigger, but for webhook, the value is generic and not updatable.

Comment: @Ari Can you please confirm if the above comment answers your question ?

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty I guess it does unfortunately. I'll just have to use the tags.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere can you please post your comment as an answer for visibility ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can't. This ref column is important when you use other type of trigger, but for webhook, the value is generic and not updatable.

Comment: Appreciated, I'll just add for others, that my current workaround is to add the pull request and branch as a dynamic tag.